# Converting UTF-16LE string with asian characters to DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utf

I'm parsing a huge set of csv files that  is generated by PowerShell.

Most of it looks as follows:

> ".txt"@"12/01/2017 4:47:55 PM"@"12/01/2017 4:47:55 PM"@"12/01/2017
>   4:47:55 PM"@"0"

But some of looks like this one:

> .pptx@"2017-02-20 오후 4:30:39"@"2017-02-20 오후 4:30:39"@"2015-11-12 오후
>   7:32:11"@"13387528"

I would like to parse DateTime objects from timestamps, but it fails:

```
pd.to_datetime ("2017-02-20 PM 4:30:39", format='%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S')
Timestamp('2017-02-20 16:30:39')

pd.to_datetime ("2017-02-20 오후 4:30:39", format='%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S')
ValueError: time data '2017-02-20 오후 4:30:39' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S' (match)
```

I can deal with this issue by opening a file as hex and just replacing corresponding '\uc624\ud6c4' with 'AM/PM'.

Am I missing more convenient way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` doesn't have a feature for this, but a trick I've used before is to excise the possibly foreign-character bit of the string:

```
pd.to_datetime(" ".join(np.array("2017-02-20 오후 4:30:39".split(" "))[[0, -1]]), 
               format='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
```

I wouldn't call this "elegant". But it works.

Comment: Yeah, I do something similar to this at the moment. Thanks!